# How to use Jupyter + SparkR and custom R install

Tags: r, jupyter, sparkr

I am using a Dockerized image and Jupyter notebook along with SparkR kernel.  When I create a SparkR notebook, it uses an install of Microsoft R (3.3.2) instead of vanilla CRAN R install (3.2.3).

The Docker image I'm using installs some custom R libraries and Python pacakages but I don't explicitly install Microsoft R. Regardless of whether or not I can remove Microsoft R or have it side-by-side, **how I can get my SparkR kernel to use a custom installation of R**?

Answer (score 2):

Docker-related issues aside, the settings for Jupyter kernels are configured in files named `kernel.json`, residing in specific directories (one per kernel) which can be seen using the command `jupyter kernelspec list`; for example, here is the case in my (Linux) machine:

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python2       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/resources
  caffe         /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/caffe
  ir            /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/ir
  pyspark       /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/pyspark
  pyspark2      /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/pyspark2
  tensorflow    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/tensorflow
```

Again, as an example, here are the contents of the `kernel.json` for my R kernel (`ir`)

```
{
  "argv": ["/usr/lib64/R/bin/R", "--slave", "-e", "IRkernel::main()", "--args", "{connection_file}"],
  "display_name": "R 3.3.2",
  "language": "R"
}
```

And here is the respective file for my `pyspark2` kernel:

```
{
 "display_name": "PySpark (Spark 2.0)",
 "language": "python",
 "argv": [
  "/opt/intel/intelpython27/bin/python2",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "env": {
  "SPARK_HOME": "/home/ctsats/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6",
  "PYTHONPATH": "/home/ctsats/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python:/home/ctsats/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip",
  "PYTHONSTARTUP": "/home/ctsats/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/shell.py",
  "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/opt/intel/intelpython27/bin/python2"
 }
}
```

As you can see, in both cases the first element of `argv` is the executable for the respective language - in my case, GNU R for my `ir` kernel and Intel Python 2.7 for my `pyspark2` kernel. Changing this, so that it points to your GNU R executable, should resolve your issue.

Comment: Briliant!! Thanks!

Comment: Yup, looks like I'm the only up vote .  But I like to focus on quality and not quantity.

Comment: Nice Job explaining the details.

Answer (score 0):

To use a custom R environment I believe you need to set the following application properties when you start Spark:

```
    "spark.r.command": "/custom/path/bin/R",
    "spark.r.driver.command": "/custom/path/bin/Rscript",
    "spark.r.shell.command" : "/custom/path/bin/R"
```

This is more completely documented here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#sparkr